# Single-sided rectifier with low pass filter

Tags: diodes, rectifier

[image]

I'm having some troubles with this simple circuit where V<sub>i</sub> is a sinusoidal signal.

If you consider that the initial voltage across the capacitor is 0 V, then until V<sub>i</sub> reaches 0,7 V the diode behaves as an open circuit. When V<sub>i</sub> reaches 0.7 V then V<sub>1</sub> = V<sub>i</sub> - 0.7 V. At this point, there will be a current which flows through the resistor and which charges the capacitor.

But I can't find a simple way to determine the voltage drop across the resistor and the capacitor, I should solve a differential equation. As a consequence I can't figure out when and if the diode will behave as a closed circuit again.

In the particular case where the value of the resistance is negligible and the voltage drop across the resistor is negligible too, I would say that V<sub>o</sub> should stay at the constant value of V<sub>i</sub>(max) - 0.7 V (the diode remains an open circuit).

I hope that someone could explain a fast and simple method to deal with this circuit and determine the signal V<sub>o</sub>(t).

Comment: you seem to be on the right way – if you consider \$V_1\$ as your input signal, this is just the question "how does the charging curve of a capacitor look like", and that's a very commonly answered thing.  Yes, your "if all effective resistances are close enough to 0" simplification seems correct enough, but is boring, because that just means your charging happens on a shorter interval than you're currently considering, and "zooming in" on an oscilloscope would tell you that your simplication wasn't good enough sooner or later.

Comment: You're however right – you need to solve a differential equation *involving* the diode when you want to accurately describe the circuit. But: the simplification "A diode is either open or has 0.7V forward drop" simply isn't good enough for this – all the interesting part of the calculation happens exactly where neither is the case. So, you will need a better model of the diode's I/V curve; keyword: Shockley diode equation.

Comment: The behavior of your circuit will depend upon the current drawn by the load. If there is no load, the capacitor will eventually charge to the input voltage (even though there is a nominal voltage drop across the diode) and then the capacitor voltage will remain there. For all other cases, you need to specify how the load will draw current.

Comment: without some form of load resistor, V0 == A-Vd  after 1/4 wave for an input of Asin(wt) since once the capacitor has charged up to the peak, it will not discharge and thus will sit there, indefinitly

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be on the right way – if you consider \$V_1\$ as your input signal, this is just the question "how does the charging curve of a capacitor look like", and that's a very commonly answered thing. Yes, your "if all effective resistances are close enough to 0" simplification seems correct enough, but is boring, because that just means your charging happens on a shorter interval than you're currently considering, and "zooming in" on an oscilloscope would tell you that your simplication wasn't good enough sooner or later. However, as you notice, this only describes the system for as long as  \$V_i - V_1 \gg 0.7 \,\text{V}\$, and that's sadly only going to be a short part of the overall time this system will need to come close to a steady state.

You're right – you need to solve a differential equation involving the diode when you want to accurately describe the circuit.

But: the simplification "A diode is either open or has 0.7V forward drop" simply isn't good enough for this – all the interesting part of the calculation happens exactly where neither is the case. So, you will need a better model of the diode's I/V curve; keyword: [Shockley diode equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley_diode_equation).

The trick is probably refreshing your experience with deriving the voltage-over-time curve of the RC part alone. That's a Classic, as you know that the voltage across the capacitor is proportional to the integral of the current flowing into it over time, and the voltage over the resistor is proportional to the current flowing into the capacitor at any time, and the sum of both voltages is the input voltage.

Now, you can apply the same trick with the diode in series to the resistor. Sadly, its voltage is not proportional to the current flowing through it – it's logarithmic. This makes for a differential equation where you have to solve something that has a function, its logarithm and its integral – you probably don't have an analytic approach for that (I don't).

So, you'd simply start by simulating this:

- zeroth nanosecond, all currents and voltages zero.
- First nanosecond, \$V_i\$ is suddenly nonzero, \$V_o\$  is still
  zero, so the voltage over diode-resistor becomes \$V_i\$, and a
  current flows which follows from the Shockley equation and the
  resistance.
- Second nanosecond, the capacitor has been charged by 1 ns
  of the current calculated above (time×current=charge), so now has a voltage. Calculate the new current, which is now lower, because the
  difference between \$V_i\$ and the capacitor voltage is now lower;
- third nanosecond, add to the capacitor voltage the voltage difference caused by the additional charge from the last nanosecond, calculate the current, and
- so on for the rest of the nanoseconds, until your output voltage doesn't change more than some \$\varepsilon\$ anymore – for example, if the newly calculated output voltage is less than 1.0001 of the last calculated one, you could call it "steady state" (if that's good enough for you).

By the way, this is pretty much what a circuit simulator (like SPICE) does under the hood: Find all nodes, calculate the currents that flow in one time step, calculate the new voltages based on the current state, then move on to the next time step.

Comment: Your answer is very detailed and interesting, but I don't need such a deep insight; I just want to stay with the simplest model for the diode (open circuit or 0.7V) and I'm interested only on a qualitative drawing of the voltage Vout over time.

Comment: Sadly, as explained, that model simply does not work, and there's no way to fix it. The capacitor simply doesn't ever reach the \$V_i-0.7\text{ V}\$ voltage in your "simple" model, so the diode never "switches off"; in reality, the output voltage does reach this voltage relatively quickly (because a diode simply does not "switch off"). As also explained, the model simply does not describe reality well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is qualitatively what's happening.

1. Initially the capacitor is empty and \$V_0(0)=0\$
2. As soon as the input voltage exceeds 0.7V the Diode opens and the capacitor starts charging and \$V_0\$ goes up.
3. When the input drops below \$V_0(t_1)+0.7V\$ the diode shuts off and \$V_0\$ stays put
4. This will repeat on the next cycle, the diode will open when \$V_i(t_2) >= V_o(t_2) + 0.7V\$ . The capacitor will get more charge, i.e. \$V_o\$ will increase and the diode shuts off at \$V_i(t_3) < V_o(t_3) + 0.7V\$
5. Over time you will get shorter and shorted charging cycles followed by longer and longer constant output.
6. The final state is \$V_o = V_{i,max}-0.7V\$

The calculation of the exact wave form is fairly complicated. You probably need to solve the differential equation for the charging segments generically for any input amplitude and phase and current capacitor voltage, determine the times of the individual sections and then splice this all together.

Here is how this looks like for a 5V sine wave at 1 kHz with \$R = 1k\Omega\$ and \$C = 1 \mu F\$ assuming an "ideal" diode.

[image]

Comment: The final state will be Vo = Vi,max. The diode will continue to conduct some current until that state is reached. Diodes do not simply "shut off" when their forward voltage drops below 0.7V.

Comment: Fair point, but then again ideal resistors and capacitors also don't exist, so you would have to model the leakage there as well.

Comment: <<< The calculation of the exact wave form is fairly complicated. >>>  One have just to write 2 equations ... Apply then "limit" conditions (start of cycle 1 (charge) = end of cycle 2 (discharge if there is one). Then just solve for this limit ... Ok, there is "some" mathematical work.

Answer (score 0):

In a theoretically perfect world, the capacitor charges up exponentially, reaching a peak value of (Vi-peak - 0.7) V.  From then on, given a cap and diode with zero leakage currents and no external connections, and an input that never is any larger, the voltage across the cap remains at Vi-peak - 0.7) V forever, no matter what the shape or frequency of the input.

As the capacitor voltage increases, the resistor differential voltage and its current decrease.  The capacitor voltage and the resistor voltage and current waveforms are exponential.  Here is the equation:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_circuit#Time-domain_considerations

Comment: the capacitor is not charging exponentially - it follows the sinusoidal input minus ~0,7 V Diode drop and minus the voltage drop of the resistor. What you mean is kind of step response if the input were rectangular.

Comment: The diode will leak and the voltage at the capacitor will eventually reach Vi(peak).

Comment: Actually, it could be a combination of both.  Assuming the Vi = 0 V at t+0, If the R-C time constant is so large that the sine wave dV/dt is greater than the initial R-C slope, the voltage curve across the cap will start out exponential, then transition to sinusoidal.

Answer (score 0):

The simple analysis is that the voltage drop across the resistor depends on the input rise time and the RC=T exponential time constant.

Knowing that Ic = C dVc / dt and the dV/dt of the input wave or step voltage or impulse, determines what to see next.

The cap has resistance or ESR will likely be lower than that of the diode, so starting with an assumption of 0.7 V depends on the type of cap. Electrolytic caps have an ESR = 200 us/C approx. for std. and <<20 us/C for "low ESR" types. This range increases with bulk size. So you can ignore this for a simple analysis.